# How to draw B-spline plots via the PROC GLIMMIX procedure in SAS?

Tags: mixed-model, sas, splines

Recently I found that the `PROC GLIMMIX` procedure in SAS added a statement `effect`, which can handle B-spline in models. I tried it, and the program looks like:

```
proc glimmix data=temp;
    effect t = spline(time);
    model y = x1 x2 t / solution;
    random intercept / subject=id type=un;
run;
```

It is ok to get outputs, but what I am really interested is the B-spline plot. I went through the entire manual, but did not find any information. Its `ODS GRAPH` function cannot generate B-spline plots automatically. Also, its `ODS OUTPUT` function does not provide any output to draw B-spline plots outside. I am wondering whether any one used to use the `PROC GLIMMIX` procedure to draw a B-spline plot? Any information is pretty appreciated!

Comment: If you don't get any answers below, when I used SAS I found their technical support to be excellent in answering these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 1):

I do the plots by using the estimate statement. That is, make some contrasts at different values of t and save the output as a table. Then it is just to plot the estimated value versus t. But maybe this is not what you are after? If you want an option that gives you the plot as output, I can't help..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do so, is to add some extra records to your dataset temp for the desired values of x1, x2 and time, but with a missing value for the outcome variable y. You obtain an output dataset for the predictions using an output statement such as

```
output out=predicted pred=pred LCL=pLCL UCL=pUCL / alpha=0.05;
```

You can then plot from the created dataset. This trick works with many SAS procdures and in general is to be preferred to working from the estimates, because the covariance matrix of the different model effects is taken into account when calculating standard errors and prediction intervals.

Comment: Having to use such tricks is a weakness in SAS compared to modern systems.  For one thing, adding new observations to the dataset may change knot locations